# Compute Eigenvalue/vector of an Array instead of Matrix with Eigen 3

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I want to compute the eigenvalue/vector of an array instead of matrix.

I tried `EigenSolver<ArrayXf>` but that gives compilation error.

I can copy the array to a matrix. But that is a waste of memory.

The follow code gives segmentation fault.

Test1:

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
using namespace Eigen;
int main() {
    ArrayXf A = ArrayXf::Ones(3,3);
    EigenSolver<MatrixXf> es(A);
}
```

Result:

```
<...>/Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h:130: 
Eigen::internal::variable_if_dynamic<T, Value>::variable_if_dynamic(T) 
[with T = long int; int Value = 1]: Assertion `v == T(Value)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I also tried `EigenSolver<MatrixXf> es(A.matrix())`. But that doesn't work too.

Test2:

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
using namespace Eigen;
int main() {
    ArrayXf A = ArrayXf::Ones(3,3);
    EigenSolver<MatrixXf> es(A.matrix());
}
```

Result:

```
<...>/XprHelper.h:130: Eigen::internal::variable_if_dynamic<T, Value>::variable_if_dynamic(T) [with T = long int; int Value = 1]: Assertion `v == T(Value)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: It's been awhile since I've taken a vector calc or linear algebra class, but IIRC, the eigenvalue of a vector doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @erip: I only change matrix in the example to array type. see https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a30430fa3d5b4e74d312fd4f502ac984d

Comment: if I understand correctly, in mathematical terms you still want to calculate the eigenvalue/vector of a matrix, just that the matrix happens to be stored as a `ArrayXf`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ArrayXf` is a 1D array whereas you want a 2D one: `ArrayXXf`.

Some history: we came up with the VectorXf/MatrixXf names before introducing Array for which there is no natural names to distinguish 1D and 2D, hence the single X versus the double XX...

Comment: Thanks. Replacing `ArrayXf` by `ArrayXXf` in test1 works. When `Ones(3,3)` caused no compilation error / run time assertion error, I thought it was fine ...